# Addressing SimpleXML elements with PHP

Tags: php

New to this and cant figure out how to refer to an element.

I'm using PHP and would like to be able to put the value that is in First_Name into a cell in an HTML table.

Thanks for any help.

Snippit of output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [organization_KEY] => 5728
    )

[supporter-supporter_KEY-supporter_groups] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [item] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [supporter_KEY] => 6147839
                        [organization_KEY] => 12345
                        [chapter_KEY] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                            )

                        [Last_Modified] => Thu Jul 09 2009 15:11:39 GMT-0400 (EDT)
                        [Date_Created] => Thu Jul 09 2009 14:44:22 GMT-0400 (EDT)
                        [Title] => Mr.
                        [First_Name] => Michael
                        [MI] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (

----------------------------------------------------

php ----------------------------------------------------
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url/getLeftJoin.sjs");
$fields = array('object' => 'supporter(supporter_KEY)supporter_groups',       'condition'=>'supporter_KEY=123456' );
echo (http_build_query($fields));
//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);
//Populate results from salsa into SimpleXML object
// See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php for more information
// on SimpleXML objects in PHP
$data = simplexml_load_string($output);
**echo ("data ". $data->supporter->First_Name);**
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item is an array, so you can address the first element in the array:

$data->supporter->item[0]->First_Name

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Try:

echo $data->{'supporter-supporter_KEY-supporter_groups'}->item->[0]->First_Name;

Curly braces prevent any interpretation of hyphens being used as subtract.

Comment: a little tweak .. echo $data->{'supporter-supporter_KEY-supporter_groups'}->item->First_Name